# Sorting XDocument elements based on InnerXML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document similar to this:

```
<document>
    <post>
      <author>Bill Smith</author>
      <subject>Test Article</subject>
      <dates>
          <uploaded>some date</uploaded>
          <published>some date</published>
      </dates>
      <price>
           <provider>Amazon</provider>
           <cost>1540</cost>
      </price>
      <price>
           <provider>WH Smith</provider>
           <cost>2640</cost>
      </price>
    </post>
    <post>
      <author>Bill Smith</author>
      <subject>Test Article</subject>
      <dates>
          <uploaded>some date</uploaded>
          <published>some date</published>
      </dates>
      <price>
           <provider>Amazon</provider>
           <cost>1540</cost>
      </price>
      <price>
           <provider>WH Smith</provider>
           <cost>2640</cost>
      </price>
    </post> 
</document>
```

I'm using XDocument w/ .NET 4.5. I know there are other methods I could use to sort this.

I have it working OK to pull each post and put it into a Post model. However, I would like to sort the price elements and pick out the lowest price (and also the provider) so I can insert it into my EF database.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm totally stuck on where to even start with this.

Comment: Share what you tried.

Comment: For each `post` you want it's minimal `cost` and `provider`?

Comment: Correct. So in this example, it would return 2 posts, with Amazon as the Provider and 1540 as the Cost.

Comment: ssilas777: what I have so far is too long to paste as a comment.

It is a Linq query, along these lines:
 `from item in resultDoc.Descendants("post")
 select new Post {
         Author = item.Element("author").Value.ToString(),
         Subject = item.Element("subject).Value.ToString(),
         AvailableDate = DateTime.Parse(item.Descendants("dates").FirstOrDefault().Value)
};`

Comment: Sort the price per post or for all the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Data.xml");
        var elements = doc.Root
            .Elements("post")
            .Select(post => new
            {
                Author = post.Element("author").Value,
                Subject = post.Element("subject").Value,
                Uploaded = Convert.ToDateTime(post.Element("dates").Element("uploaded").Value),
                Published = Convert.ToDateTime(post.Element("dates").Element("published").Value),
                Price = new
                {
                    P = post
                        .Elements("price")
                        .OrderByDescending(price => Convert.ToDecimal(price.Element("cost").Value))
                        .Select(o => new
                        {
                            Provider = o.Element("provider").Value,
                            Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(o.Element("cost").Value)
                        })
                        .First()
                }
            });

        var p = elements.First();
```

Comment: sorting is probably not required if OP just wants the minimum.

Comment: Ok. However, how do I combine this with what I have so far to get the other values (author, subject, published) out of it?

Comment: @publicgk Sorting and taking first element is part of this approach, to do it with only minimum value would be a different approach.

Comment: @MartinAlderson All the data for `post` element can be retrieved as , for instance, for the first element: `XElement p = elements.First().Post;`. Anonymous type created by `Select` contains 3 `XElement` objects, one for `post`, one for `cost` and one for `provider`.

Comment: Am I completely off course with something like:
Price = Convert.ToDecimal(item.Elements("price").OrderBy(price => Convert.ToDecimal(price.Element("cost").Value)).First().Value) - this doesn't work (null reference?

Comment: @MartinAlderson I don't think that would work, you can't use the result provided in my query? Which part needs to be changed?

Comment: Ok, so I understand, how do I then combine the post with the cost & provider? The example that publicgk gives makes more sense to me, but you are right that it doesn't give a provider. Thanks very much for your help so far.

Comment: Note that I added conversion into `DateTime` for `dates/uploaded` and `dates/published`, so you have to add some real dates into sample data or just comment out those lines if you dont need that information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on code you provided, see, if this works:

```
var xmlDocumentElement = xDocument.Load("xmlData.xml").Root;

var posts = xmlDocumentElement.Elements("post").Select(post => new 
    {
    Author = post.Element("author").Value.ToString(),
    Subject = post.Element("subject").Value.ToString(),
    AvailableDate = DateTime.Parse(post.Descendants("dates").FirstOrDefault().Value),
    Price = GetPriceFromPriceXElement(post.Elements("price").Aggregate((prev, next) => 
            Decimal.Parse(prev.Element("cost").Value.ToString()) <= Decimal.Parse(next.Element("cost").Value.ToString()) ? prev : next ))
    }
    );

public Price GetPriceFromPriceXElement(XElement price)
{
   return new Price
    { 
        Provider = price.Element("provider").Value.ToString(),
        Cost = price.Element("cost").Value.ToString()
    };
}
```

Comment: wouldn't provider be automatically part of the price elements?

Comment: won't [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534802.aspx) return the price element, because it's applied on the list of price elements? Edited to change price element to Price model.

Comment: ah.. i see. it will return double. Probably, he will have to use aggregate then. Thanks for the correction, Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work. Once you've data, you can massage it. Please take care of `NULL` etc. This is just basic idea around your requirement.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
        var posts = doc.Root.Elements("post")
                   .Select(p =>
                            new
                            {
                               Author = p.Element("author").Value,
                               Price = p.Elements("price").OrderBy(a => decimal.Parse(a.Element("cost").Value)).First()
                     });

        foreach(var a in posts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Author + " " + a.Price);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty straightforward attempt (and actually very similar to Ivan G's answer):

```
var posts = from post in document.Root.Elements("post")
            select new
            {
                Author = post.Element("author").Value,
                Subject = post.Element("subject").Value,
                Uploaded = DateTime.Parse(post.Element("dates").Element("uploaded").Value),
                Published = DateTime.Parse(post.Element("dates").Element("published").Value),
                Price = (from price in post.Elements("price")
                         let cost = decimal.Parse(price.Element("cost").Value)
                         orderby cost
                         select new
                         {
                             Provider = price.Element("provider").Value,
                             Cost = cost
                         }).First()
            };
```

It works fine for the sample data you gave us (except the dates "some date").

If the data might be incomplete or wrong (i.e. missing/misspelled nodes or wrong datatypes) I would suggest to just take each `XElement` instead of the values: `Author = post.Element("author")` etc. Maybe you want to allow posts without an uploaded or published date. This way you can inspect and/or cast/convert data later and maybe fix problems properly.